# Why doesn't C++ standard library has stream output for standard containers? (and related problems)

Tags: c++

Simply put why there is no overload for `operator<<` of `basic_ostream` and standard containers like `vector` or `pair`. Like there is for `string`.

It would be so easy if there would be a standard way to print these objects.

---

I wondered for a long time why this is simply as a curiosity (and laziness to write such an operator for every little program where I wanted to quickly output a vector). But now I encountered a **real problem** caused by this:

I am implementing a library. I have an exception class `utils::exception::OutOfRange`. The constructor takes as an argument an object representing the `key` that is out of range. I use `stringstream` (and other stuff) to create (a comprehensive) error message:

```
template <class Key>
inline OutOfRange::OutOfRange(const Key &key) : Exception(2) {
  //just the interesting part (a simplified version):
  string_stream message;
  message << "accessed at key/index '"<< key; // <-- there must be an operator<< for key
}
```

For a `vector like container`, the `key` can be an `int` so everything is fine. For a `map like container` the `key` can be anything, but this requires that there has to be such an `operator<<`. But it kind of makes sense to force the user to have an `operator<<` if he wishes to throw an `OutOfRange` object. Is that OK?

**The real dilemma** came from this: Now I implement a `Matrix` class (within the same library) that throws `OutOfRange`. The `Key` for this is a `std::pair<int, int>`. So I am responsible to provide an `operator<<` for `std::pair`. But it doesn't seem OK that including a header that defines a `Matrix` class will also bring (silently and unrelatedly) an overload for `operator<<(ostream, std::pair)`. Conflicts can appear if the user also has such an overload.

I feel like all this could easily be avoided if there were such operators in the standard library for the containers defined in the standard library.

Am I missing something? Is my approach to create the message wrong?

<sub>Apologies if my questions are all over the palace. I tried to tied them all together in a rounded and logical way, don't know how much I succeeded.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the standard library doesn't overload `operator<<` for containers is obvious: Users have vastly different expectations for output (think alone about the delimiter! for `vector<int>`, a space or comma may be good, for `vector<vector<int>>` a newline may be better). There is no "one correct" overload. This is of course different for `std::string` which is mainly not thought of as a container, but, well, a string.

For your second problem: You may want to reconsider your design and just use `std::out_of_range`. You can also specialize your template for specific containers and perform the printing with specialized methods rather than `operator<<`.

Another well-established way to print ranges is to use ostream iterators:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::ostream_iterator
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector;
  for (int i=1; i<10; ++i) myvector.push_back(i*10);

  std::ostream_iterator<int> out_it (std::cout,", ");
  std::copy ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), out_it );
  return 0;
}
```

(This example code was copied from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/))

Comment: Re `operator<<` for containers, I disagree. The point of operator overloading is to allow the same syntax to work with different types. Printing containers is not rocket science; just choose one style of formatting that works for most cases (as many other programming languages do). If you dislike the standard choice, you can always output things by hand.

Comment: By defining `operator<<` you're taking the possibility for the user to do that away. That's a terrible idea for just the reasons I stated six years ago. Other languages solve it differently (e.g. by inheritance and overriding of `ToString`)

Comment: `operator<<` could live in a separate namespace and users would have to opt in via `using namespace...`. Much like what the stdlib does with `chrono_literals`. At the end of the day it's slightly embarrassing for a language in 2021 to not support printing basic sequence containers. Your arguments apply to other languages as well and most of them support printing sequences.

Answer (score 1):

*You* are trying to write out the key, *you* are responsible for the ramifications of your decision/design.

The problem is that "just print out an object of type foo" has *no* single answer. Perhaps what for me is a pair giving longitude and latitude (and thus should be shown in degrees, minutes, seconds, and decimal fraction) for you is a pair of numbers to be written with two decimals in parentesis. And that is just a simple case, what about some complex class? Write out the public members as names/values? Protected, private stuff? Static members? Mark base class(es) somehow?

Comment: Coincidentally, there is one right answer in Python - it prints anything.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, completely different problem space targeted.